# Docker container IDs clash in concurrent Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins, makefile, jenkins-pipeline, repository

I'm using Jenkins, Docker and a Makefile to run a pipeline in my Jenkins. The issue is the container IDs clash (obviously) when 2 builds from the same repository are running concurrently. The container names are defined in the Makefile

```
TEST_IMAGE = test-image-python
TEST_CONTAINER = test-container-python

run_tests: # using reports
    docker run -d --name $(TEST_CONTAINER) $(TEST_IMAGE)
```

I'm using a (declarative) Jenkinsfile to set up the stages of the Jenkins pipeline, where the `make run_tests` command is executed. I've tried the `options {disableConcurrentBuilds()}` option, but that apparently only works for the same branch of the repository, and limiting Jenkins to run at only one at a time seems like a suboptimal solution.

What I thought of doing was adjusting the Makefile to append some kind of uuid to the container name, but I can't figure out how to do it. What I found for bash to generate a UUID is

```
UUID=$(cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/uuid)
```

which I tried to get into the Makefile with

```
generate_uuid:
    bash UUID=$$(cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/uuid)
    echo $(UUID)
```

... which doesn't work. In the end what I would like to have is either

```
TEST_CONTAINER = test-container-python_$(UUID)
```

or alternatively I could generate the UUID and append it when calling `docker run`

```
run_tests: # using reports
    docker run -d --name $(TEST_CONTAINER)_$(UUID) $(TEST_IMAGE)
```

I'm fine with either, I'm just not sure how to get the last step done.

Comment: Why not just use [predefined environment variables](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#using-environment-variables) of `BUILD_ID`, `BUILD_NUMBER` or `BUILD_TAG` instead of attempting to generate UUID?

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize there was such a thing! That should work much better than what I had planned. I'll try on monday, thanks!